# Iterator Algorithm Efficiency

Tags: java

I am not sure if my algorithm is efficient or not with using Iterator. I am implementing a solitaire matching game for my lab assignment in which you have a list of random integer values between 10 and 99. You remove from the list any pair of consecutive integers whose first or second digits match. If all values are removed, then you win.

For example, consider the following sequence of 10 integers:

> 10 82 43 23 89 12 43 84 23 32

I will have to iterate in the list to compare the integer values and check for matching. If there is a matched those two integer values will be removed and everytime there is a removed pair it will do another pass to compare and check again until there is no any matching values detected.

The final output will be this:

> 43 84 23 32

I will have to implement this following method

```
public static boolean scanAndRemovePairs(ArrayListWithIterator<Integer> theList)
```

Which we will be using an **Iterator** (not a ListIterator), scans the list and removes matching pairs of values. This method will scans over the list and removes any pairs of values that are removable. The method will return true if any pair of integers was removed.

This is my current implementation for the algorithm:

**scanAndRemovePairs Method**

```
public static boolean scanAndRemovePairs(ArrayListWithIterator<Integer> theList)
{
    //Pairs removed indicator
    boolean pairsRemoved = false;
    //Make a copy of the original
    ArrayListWithIterator<Integer> theListCopy = new ArrayListWithIterator<>(COUNT);
    for(Integer value : theList)
        theListCopy.add(value);
    //Make a separate iterator for the copy list        
    for(Iterator<Integer> iteratorCopy = theListCopy.getIterator(); iteratorCopy.hasNext();)
    {
        //Advance iteratorCopy to first element
        iteratorCopy.next(); 
        //Iterate through the original list
        for(Iterator<Integer> iterator = theList.getIterator(); iterator.hasNext();)
        {
            //Set first element from original list
            Integer first = iterator.next();
            //If first element from original list has next element
            if(iterator.hasNext())
            {
                //Get second element from other iterator
                Integer second = iteratorCopy.next();
                //If first and second integer is removable
                if(removable(first, second))
                {
                    //Remove the first and second integer from the original list
                    iterator.remove();
                    iterator.next();
                    iterator.remove();
                    //If original list has a next element advance iteratorCopy to point as same as the original
                    if(iterator.hasNext()) iteratorCopy.next();
                    System.out.printf("   Removed: %d  %d\n", first, second);
                    pairsRemoved = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return pairsRemoved;
} // end scanAndRemovePairs
```

**Main Method**

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ArrayListWithIterator<Integer> theList = new ArrayListWithIterator<>(COUNT);
    initializeList(theList);
    System.out.print("The list is originally: ");
    displayList(theList);
    while(scanAndRemovePairs(theList)) 
    {
        System.out.print("The list is now: ");
        displayList(theList);
    }
    if(theList.getLength() == 0)
        System.out.println("You won!");
    else
    {
        if(theList.getLength() == COUNT) 
            System.out.println("You got no pairs.");
        else
            System.out.println("No more pairs to remove.");
        System.out.println("You lose!");
    }
} // end main
```

**Test Run Output**

```
The list is originally: [17, 73, 68, 14, 91, 18, 80, 41, 23, 46, 73, 53, 76, 45, 97, 18, 80, 33, 28, 93, 24, 62, 85, 64, 66, 75, 22, 31, 39, 83, 16, 28, 11, 14, 70, 25, 39, 75, 94, 40]
   Removed: 73  53
   Removed: 64  66
   Removed: 31  39
   Removed: 11  14
The list is now: [17, 73, 68, 14, 91, 18, 80, 41, 23, 46, 76, 45, 97, 18, 80, 33, 28, 93, 24, 62, 85, 75, 22, 83, 16, 28, 70, 25, 39, 75, 94, 40]
   Removed: 46  76
   Removed: 85  75
The list is now: [17, 73, 68, 14, 91, 18, 80, 41, 23, 45, 97, 18, 80, 33, 28, 93, 24, 62, 22, 83, 16, 28, 70, 25, 39, 75, 94, 40]
   Removed: 62  22
The list is now: [17, 73, 68, 14, 91, 18, 80, 41, 23, 45, 97, 18, 80, 33, 28, 93, 24, 83, 16, 28, 70, 25, 39, 75, 94, 40]
No more pairs to remove.
You lose!
```

So my question is, is my algorithm efficient the way I implemented it? or is there a simple and better way to solve this problem? Any ideas?

Comment: Usually, _check my working code_ or _improve my algorithm_ type questions are better suited for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Do you _have_ to use an iterator? And since `ArrayListWithIterator` is a class we don't know (it's not a standard JDK class) what kind of iterator does it return? Anything more specific than `Iterator<Integer>`?

Comment: In general iterators are efficient enough. They are used all the time.

Comment: @Thomas Yes, according to my lab assignment that's what we have to use. ArrayListWithIterator class has an inner class iterator which implements Iterator. So it returns a class Iterator.

Comment: Is that a `java.util.Iterator` or some iterator that also supports going back?

Comment: Yes, a java.util.Iterator.